# How to set rel="nofollow" links with summernote

Tags: nofollow, summernote

I have a problem. I would like set rel="nofollow" Links in my summernote editor. 
I tried to rng.insertNode($('' + sLinkText + '')[0]); on line 1757 but it doesn't work.

Can someone help me please?

THX